# what is the type of flatbuffer in call to UnPackTo

Tags: c++11, flatbuffers

I just started to understand how flatbuffers work. The document is good. In the section for usage in c++ i see following example

```
// Autogenerated class from table Monster.
MonsterT monsterobj;

// Deserialize from buffer into object.
UnPackTo(&monsterobj, flatbuffer);

// Update object directly like a C++ class instance.
cout << monsterobj->name;  // This is now a std::string!
monsterobj->name = "Bob";  // Change the name.

// Serialize into new flatbuffer.
FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
Pack(fbb, &monsterobj);
```

My question is what is the type of flatbuffer? no where in the document it mentioned. Is it the binary buffer either read from file or received over network?

This is the link from where i copied the above sample code.

https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html

Answer (score 3):

That documentation looks out of date, it should probably be `GetMonster(flatbuffer)->UnPackTo(&monsterobj)` where `flatbuffer` is a pointer to the bytes containing the binary FlatBuffer representation.

The above however is part of the "object API", which you should only be using is convenience is more important than performance. Read about the base API here: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html

Comment: i dug into the generated code and figured this out, but your post confirmed it! Thanks a ton!